# Mutable Dictionary Keys not being set properly

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, nsmutabledictionary

I have an `NSMutableDictionary` that is a synthesized property of a class. When I initialize the class I add several key value pairs to the dictionary, I am unable to later retrieve them and get a null result.

Some code:

```
[self.sections setValue:@"first" forKey:@"Some_Key"];
// sections is the synthesized NSMutableDictionary property
NSLog(@"First: %@", [self.sections valueForKey:@"Some_Key"]);
```

I get this in the log: `First: (null)`

Is there something I am omitting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your dictionary itself is `nil`. In your initialization, add `[self setSections:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]]`. That way, you've got an empty dictionary awaiting new values.

(I'm guessing this because one can message `nil`, and it will return `nil` for anything--just like you're getting when you ask for your value back.)